# windows kernel debugging over a network issues

Tags: windows, windbg, remote-debugging, device-driver, visual-studio-debugging

I'm trying to get windows kernel debugging to work over a network.

My NIC is on the list of "Network Adapters Supported for Debugging."
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh830880

Hardware ID: PCI\VEN_14E4&DEV_166A&SUBSYS_166A14E4&REV_10

I've tried setting it with [Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and I've tried [setting it up manually](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439346%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The NIC is built into the mother board (Tyan s3992) and there are two ports.  I tried setting busparams for both but neither worked.  Neither would get a DHCP address.  I tried to get it working with the automatic private IP address but that didn't work either.  I couldn't ping between host and target.  I ran netmon on the host computer but could not see any traffic with the mac address on the "Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter"

In device manager, there is a yellow exclamation on whichever NIC I use by setting busparams and the device status says "This device is not working properly because Windows cannot load the drivers required for this device. (Code 31)" Is this device supposed to be working when network debugging is enabled or does the "Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter" take control of it and this is what's supposed to happen?

I have 8gb of memory in the system.  I removed some DIMMs and I tried with only 4gb of memory but nothing as well.

Any help would be appreciated.

Target machine is Windows Server 2012.

Running: bcdedit /dbgsettings

Produces the following output:

busparams               4.4.0

key                     32tmoweft93we.1nj5p5surraxg.2y62zugpzjj0p.3salu7uqd9hyg

debugtype               NET

hostip                  192.168.231.23

port                    50000

dhcp                    Yes

The operation completed successfully.

Comment: Just curious that initially before starting your setup, were you able to ping host from the target?

Comment: Yes.  Communications was working prior to making the bcd changes. No DHCP packets or ARP frames from the target can be seen by the host after the bcd changes.

Comment: Could you update the thread with more details on the target machine operating system(Win7 or Win8) and dump of 'bcdedit' command output from the target machine?

Comment: I updated the post with the bcd dbgsettings.  Would an entire listing of the bcd be useful?  I have multiple boot entries that boot from vhdx differencing disk.